# Why does reopen use a system dialog?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, vote-to-close, reopen-closed

Why does reopen (a question) use a system-style dialog while close uses a custom one?

Comment: It's probably just quicker for a simple Yes/No.

Comment: @random: I think you're probably right, but I think part of good UI design is consistency. (that makes me laugh, by the way, "@random")

Comment: So do delete and undelete dialogs. The Close dialog is different because a reason for closing is required.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to close a question, you must select a reason you think it should be closed, as there are many different reasons it could be inappropriate for the site. This is then sent off to the servers for others to vote on in the close queue, and to show as a message if the question is closed.

Reopen however means only one thing: "This question is ok" and there's no further input from the user required to register their vote. The dialogue is simply a Javascript "Are you sure?" to prevent accidental votes being cast.

It's also consistent with some other "Are you sure?"s on the site, like when you retract a comment vote you get a system message confirmation too.